# Setting GraphicsDevice to 30Hz Refresh Actually Sets 29Hz. Why?

Tags: java, refresh, fullscreen

I am using Java SE8 on Windows 10 to set my ViewSonic VX2453 monitor to a 30Hz refresh rate when it is in full-screen mode. When I query the device, however, it reports that it is set to 29Hz. Both 30Hz and 29Hz are listed among the display modes available for the monitor. Here's my code, which reports all of the available display modes for each of the three monitors on my computer. The VX2453 is the first of the three:

```java
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Refresh
{
    JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Refresh main = new Refresh();

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(main::init);
    }

    void init()
    {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gd[] = ge.getScreenDevices();

        for (int device = 0; device < gd.length; device++)
        {
            DisplayMode dm[] = gd[device].getDisplayModes();

            System.out.printf("Device %d:\n", device);

            for (int mode = 0; mode < dm.length; mode++)
            {
                System.out.printf("dm[%2d]: %4d x %4d : %2d - %3d\n",
                        mode,
                        dm[mode].getWidth(),
                        dm[mode].getHeight(),
                        dm[mode].getBitDepth(),
                        dm[mode].getRefreshRate());
            }
        }

        GraphicsDevice myDevice = gd[0];

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);

        try
        {
            myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
            myDevice.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(1920, 1080, 32, 30));
            DisplayMode m = myDevice.getDisplayMode();

            System.out.printf("%d x %d %d - %d\n", m.getWidth(), m.getHeight(), m.getBitDepth(), m.getRefreshRate());
        }
        finally
        {
            myDevice.setFullScreenWindow(null);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Here's my output (with extraneous lines edited out):

```
run:
Device 0:
dm[ 0]:  640 x  480 : 32 -  56
...
dm[40]: 1920 x 1080 : 32 -  29
...
dm[43]: 1920 x 1080 : 32 -  30
...
dm[45]: 1400 x 1050 : 32 -  60
Device 1:
dm[ 0]:  768 x 1024 : 32 -  75
...
dm[18]:  600 x  800 : 32 -  56
Device 2:
dm[ 0]:  768 x 1024 : 32 -  75
...
dm[22]:  720 x 1280 : 32 -  60
1920 x 1080 32 - 29
```

The monitor is initially at 60Hz before the program runs.

setDisplayMode throws an IllegalArgumentException if any of its parameters are not supported by the GraphicsDevice. My call, asking for 30Hz, does not throw an exception (but, as a test, a call asking for 31Hz does thrown an exception).

Why does a successful call to setDisplayMode specifying a refresh rate of 30Hz end up returning 29Hz in a subsequent call to getDisplayMode?

**UPDATE:**

As Durandl suggested, I checked the actual refresh rate after each requested change. Here's what I got

```
Asked for  Reported  Actual
   59         60      60.1
   60         60      60.1
   25         25      49.9
   50         50      50.0
   29         29      59.9
   30         29      60.0
```

Now, in "PC" mode, the monitor's menu reports my screen resolution as "1920x1080," for all the rates above (which is what I asked for). But, in "AV" mode (where it slightly overscans the physical screen), the monitor's menu reports it as either "1080p" or "1080i." For all the refresh rates *below* 50, it is 1080i. For all of them at 50 or above, it is 1080p. Thus, as it appears the lower rates all put the monitor into interlaced mode, that explains why the vertical frequency is (roughly) twice the requested refresh rate. That part makes sense, as does the slight departure the monitor reports from the integral values requested. But it still doesn't explain why a request for "30" returns "29."

Interestingly, there is no screen flicker in the "change" from 59Hz to 60Hz, both of which report 60 from getDisplayMode, nor is there any screen flicker in the "change" from 29Hz to 30Hz, both of which report 29 from getDisplayMode. I'm guessing those pairs of modes are actually the same, in operation.

Still puzzled about the odd return value.

Comment: Confirm the supported refresh rates with an independent utility. DisplayMode refresh rate is an int, but supported refresh rates are often very odd (e.g. 29.97hz) and there might be rounding/select nearest involved.

Comment: Will do. Back soon to report...

Comment: I had to query the monitor's own internal menu to find out what refresh rate it reported, as using either of the monitors not in fullscreen mode took the first monitor out of fullscreen mode. That is, I couldn't run a utility on another screen while the first screen was in fullscreen mode. My results are in the update to my original question. above.